# How to get Swig to generate a Python class instead of free functions?

Tags: c++, swig

How can I get Swig generate Python code as a class instead of free functions?

```
%module SimulatorAppWrapper
%{
#define SWIG_FILE_WITH_INIT
#include "SimulatorAppWrapper.hpp"
%}

%include "SimulatorAppWrapper.hpp"
```

My wrapper source is fairly trivial:

```
class SimulatorAppWrapper
{
public:

    typedef std::map<const char*, const char*> ConfigSettings;

    SimulatorAppWrapper();

    ~SimulatorAppWrapper();

    void AddConfigKey(const char* k, const char* v); 

    int Run();
};
```

From here I generate Swig source and link against it using:
swig -python -c++ SimulatorAppWrapper.i

However I check the build module I get the following where I have free functions instead of something like a class:

```
>>> import SimulatorAppWrapper
>>> dir(_SimulatorAppWrapper)
['SWIG_PyInstanceMethod_New', 'SimulatorAppWrapper_AddConfigKey', 'SimulatorAppWrapper_Run', 'SimulatorAppWrapper_swigregister', '__doc__', '__file__', '__name__', '__package__', 'delete_SimulatorAppWrapper', 'new_SimulatorAppWrapper']
```

I would like to be able to do something like the following:

```
simApp = SimulatorAppWrapper
simApp.Run()
```

Answer (score 1):

I can't see anything wrong with the SWIG .i or your .h.

But your test would be `simApp = SimulatorAppWrapper()` (note the parentheses) then either semicolon or new line before `simApp.Run()`.

Also you should use `from SimulatorAppWrapper import SimulatorAppWrapper` since you have named your module `SimulatorAppWrapper`.

Finally, you do not need an underscore in `dir(_SimulatorAppWrapper)`. The list you see is the set of SWIG wrapper functions which get called when you create instance, etc. For example when you call `SimulatorAppWrapper()` this actually calls `new_SimulatorAppWrapper()`. Try `dir(SimulatorAppWrapper)` (which in your original code will be `dir()` on the module object, but if you use the "from import" as I suggest above it will be `dir()` on your class).